# Any natural interpretation for "hopfield network is all you need"?

Tags: neural-networks, attention

I am studying deep learning and came across to the paper claiming "so-called attention mechanism in deep learning is equivalent to hopfield network", in the paper called "Hopfield network is all you need".
(https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.02217.pdf)
However, I still doesn't fully get the physical intuition of the correspondence.
In my opinion, equation 2 and 3 in the paper should come from transition probability of MCMC or something,
but I quite don't understand why.
In particular, could someone explain

- where $\beta^{-1} \log N$ term and $\frac{1}{2}M^2$ term come from
- relationship between transition of $\xi$ and MCMC

I would really appreciate your help,